# how to insert a line break into a header using cURL

Tags: curl, http-headers, newline

I want to use cURL to test a RESTful web service resource.

In that effort, one of the headers requires a linebreak to properly pass the data to the server.

In addition to endlessly searching for what I would think would be fairly common to no avail, I have tried using (**\n**):

```
curl -X POST --header "login_id: testUser" --header "passcode: testPasscode" --header "dataHeader: some data\nsome more data"  http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

which does not work.  The line break is not recognized when the header is read at the server - I think cURL actually removes it.

I have also tried using (**%0A**):

```
curl -X POST --header "login_id: testUser" --header "passcode: testPasscode" --header "dataHeader: some data%0Asome more data"  http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

How should I craft the post to insert a line break between `some data` and `some more data`?

I am using terminal on a Mac

Comment: You might want to try to use both line feed and carriage return.  So `--header "dataHeader: some data\r\nsome more data"`  Also, you're missing closing quotes on that header string but I figured that's just a SO typo

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either.  It appears both the line line and carriage return are removed when cURL encodes the header.

Comment: Have you tried using a separate `--header` switch for the second line?

Comment: The specification requires the data to be in one header.  I don't make the rules, I am just trying to follow and subsequently test them.  I can do this from Java, but would like to use cURL if possible.

Comment: I don't think curl removes the `\n`. Try `curl -v -H "dataHeader: some data\nsome more data" -o /dev/null example.com`.

Comment: Regarding @pauldom's comment, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style). But you already tried it anyway.

Comment: One last shot - Have you tried just sending it with `\r`?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771077/php-and-http-header-line-breaks-what-character-used-to-represent) makes me think that `\n` might be the problem.

Comment: Agreed.  I have researched http protocol and the url-encoded new line character must be used.  So I have refactored and will have to use `%0A`.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a raw line break from the command line:

```
$ curl -X POST [...] --header "dataHeader: some data<press ENTER>
> some more data" http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

Comment: Type it the way it's written. Leave the double-quotes open, press enter, and continue on the second line.

Comment: My confusion lies in that hitting enter "sends" the command and results in the terminal displaying "Unmatched ".""

Comment: Which shell are you using? It works in bash and sh, at least. Leaving the quotes open should yield a second line with the PS2 prompt (usually ">").

Comment: Terminal on my Macbook Pro

Comment: What happens when you type 'echo "test' (without the single quotes) on the command line? OSX should use Bash.

Comment: [Macintosh-2:~] % echo "test"
test
[Macintosh-2:~] %

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34484/discussion-between-romulo-ceccon-and-android-addict)

Comment: The curl manual page says: "curl will make sure that each header you add/replace is sent with the proper end-of-line marker, you should thus not add that as a part of the header content: do not add newlines or carriage returns, they will only mess things up for you."

Comment: I require a new line marker - not an end-of-line marker.  The data that will be sent in production will have new line characters in it.  I can do this by POSTing from Java, but I want to do this with cURL.